# Magento 2 Checkout: Apply custom field validation rule only on submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, magento2, checkout

In Magento CE2.4.5 I have added a custom validation to the STREET field. It needs to be validated if the field contains both text and a number as many customers forget to submit their house number:

```
'validate-housenumber': [
        function (value) {
            return utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || /^[A-Za-z]+[ ]+[0-9]/.test(value);
        },
        $.mage.__('Please enter a house number')
    ],
```

For testing reasons I have added this code in:

*Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js*

And added the validation rule in:

*checkout_index_index.xml*

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
<item name="validate-housenumber" xsi:type="string">true</item>
</item>
```

However, the validation happens immediately when starting to type anything in the field. I would need either one of these solutions:

**(a)** Validation message appears after leaving the field (desired)

**(b)** Validation message appears after clicking the button to the next checkout step (just like it happens with required fields not being filled out)

Any hint would be very welcome. Thank you for your help!

Alex

Comment: the code you show seems ok, but where the validation of "validate-housenumber" is triggered, there is the problem

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But what exactly do you mean? Does the code need to be placed in another file?

Comment: I mean in your template somewhere the 'validate-housenumber' is included for that field, that code is making it trigger on any keyup or something, that needs to delay abit, or trigger on post of form instead of change of form

Comment: I have included the validation rule in "checkout_index_index.xml". Is there another way?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/c3ad5110e4e264384475ab0cad41ad3bfbcf870e/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js did you use rules.js instead of rule.js?

Comment: And also did you use: setup:upgrade, setup:di-compile, setup:static-content:deploy -f, and clear caches

Comment: That was a typo. I added it to rules.js. Compilation etc. should not be the point here as the rule is basically working. I just need to change the immediate validation to validation after either leaving the field or when trying to send the form.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution in another Thread. Thanks to *Tailtiu*:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278554/trigger-checkout-validation-only-on-change-event

With this solution validation works as expected. However, for testing reasons I applied the validation to *company* field instead of *street* field:

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validate-housenumber" xsi:type="string">true</item
  </item>                                                               
  <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/form/element/inputhousenumbercheck</item></item>                                                       
</item>
```

This works fine. But when applying it to the field **street.0** instead of company field there is a problem: in frontend the street field cannot be accessed any more.

**Update:**
As I learnt the street field cannot be accessed via xml. Instead it had to be done via plugin for:

```
Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor
```